# Don't want to insert 0 value in half day and short leave case

Tags: php

its works well for `leave_type = 11` but for `leave_type = 3` still it insert 0
don't know how to solve this

`leave_type = 3` is for half day
`leave_type = 11` is for short leave day

```
'days' => ($this->input->post('leave_type') == 3) ? 0.5 : ($this->input->post('leave_type') == 11) ? 0 :$days_between ,
```

please provide solution

Comment: First remove comma from end and add semicolon then check if your Database field is integer type then make it float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you're not grouping your **ternary operator**.

```
($this->input->post('leave_type') == 3) ? 0.5 : (($this->input->post('leave_type') == 11) ? 0 :$days_between)
                                                ^                                       ^
```

The explanation here is because in your original code, it evaluates first the condition on the left, which is `($this->input->post('leave_type') == 3) ? 0.5 : (($this->input->post('leave_type') == 11)`

Which, in your case, should be `0.5`. But, because there is another ternary operator on the right, the `0.5` will be converted to a **boolean** type, which would be `true`. So, because the evaluation passed to the next ternary operator is **true**, the returned value would then be `0`.

```
true ? 0 : $days_between
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below:

```
'days' => ($this->input->post('leave_type') == 3) ? '0.5' : (($this->input->post('leave_type') == 11) ? 0 :$days_between) ,
```

Answer (score 1):

This is related to your database field data type.You must have set that field data type to integer.You need to set it to float.